# How much bandwith is needed for my website

Tags: web, browser, performance-testing, pagespeed, bandwidth

i have a website what can be used by 50 users at the same time. Those users will be in the same room.

My problem is to know how much bandwith (in Mb/s) do I need to rent for that room so that they can access my website comfortably (speed up and down) ?

The average page size of my website is 1MB.

I searched for answers on the internet and all I got was bandwith used in a month (for servers).

Sorry if my question is "vague", I did my best to make it clear.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Using https://gtmetrix.com/ you can test your websites speed, page size, and load times

There are several alternatives you just have to do the research

The more important issue you should focus on is why your page is 1Mb that should be your first priority to resolve and using tools like gtmetrix can help

Answer (score 1):

I recommend load testing your site to figure that out.  If you're at all familiar with JMeter, you can use it to create a script that simulates a user navigating your site, then run multiple instances of that user (in your case, 50) to see how the site holds up under load.

You can learn more about JMeter here:
https://jmeter.apache.org/

If you're not familiar with creating JMeter scripts, you can record and auto-generate basic scripts using the Blazemeter Chrome Extension, [here](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension:-Record-JMeter,-Selenium,-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium).

For low-load testing (50 users is pretty low), you can upload your JMeter script to Blazemeter, and with a free tier Blazemeter account, you can perform some basic tests to see how your site holds up.  If you go that route, I recommend focusing on avg. response time and hits/second in order to determine what your bandwidth need truly is under load.